# Show subdomain as domain on IIS 6

Tags: c#, iis

I want to show subdomain.domain/somfolder as domain/somfolder on clients browser? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Add a host header for domain as well as for sub-domain.domain for your web-site, and make sure domain and subdomain.domain points to the same IP address in your DNS (or have your IIS server responds to both addresses if they are different).

[Set host headers in IIS6](http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/)

[Set host headers in IIS7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx)